# proper way of renaming / backing up files

Tags: excel, ms-access, backup

i am constantly making changes to access and excel file macros and databases. what i usually do before i modify the file is i make a copy of the file and rename it to the `filename_todaysdate.ext`. is this the proper/safest way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backup strategy is based on copying the entire Excel or Access file ... which may be just fine for your requirements.  I don't do much Excel, but with Access there are many times I prefer saving just selected pieces rather than a complete copy of the entire MDB.  You can imagine how much disk space would be consumed by multiple copies of a large MDB ... say hundreds of megabytes, for example.

You can use the undocumented SaveAsText method to save individual database objects to text files:

```
Application.SaveAsText acForm, "frmFoo", "C:\Backup\frmFoo.txt"
```

O'Reilly's Access Cookbook offers another granular approach to backing up database objects.  See [Recipe 6.8 Back Up Selected Objects to Another Database](http://etutorials.org/Microsoft+Products/access/Chapter+6.+Data/Recipe+6.8+Back+Up+Selected+Objects+to+Another+Database/)

Answer (score 2):

Any way can be the 'right' way as long as you are consistent and everyone knows the system.
That said, I would change the extension: `filename_date_ext.old` and moving the backup files to a folder clearly marked 'backup' in order to easily sort out the backups and prevent accidental use of old data. After all, some original filenames may contain the date too!

Comment: @HansUp: Good suggestion. I took it for granted that backups would not be stored in the same place, but it's worth a mention. I've added it to the answer.